# Is it possible to invoke a servlet with using a form?

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to invoke a servlet with using a form? I want to invoke a servlet but I do not want the user to have to click a button or link. Is this possible?

Comment: when should the servlet be invoked?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario more specifically?

Comment: After authenticating into a login page the servlet should be invoked. After logging in, the user will be taken to another jsp page. It is at this point that the program will process some information displaying attributes of the user who just logged in. Does this make sense?

Comment: Why do you need a POST for this? You can achieve it using GET.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really intend to do but looks like you want to submit your form automatically (without user intervention).
In this case you will have to create a `POST` request yourself and submit it.
You can use `Apache HttpClient` for this purpose.

Comment: This does not make sense. The form is to be displayed by a browser, thus submitting will require client-side technology (i.e. JavaScript). HttpClient is a Java component, suitable for using it on the server (unless you don't plan on running an Applet...).

Comment: As mentioned I was not sure about the intention and has already commented about it after OP clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a JavaScript.
Create form with name="form1"

```
<form name="form1" class="form1" action="path_of_servlet">
  <input type="text" name="form-name"><br>
</form>
```

Submit the form using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.form1.submit();</script>
```